# Understanding CompletableFuture::runAsync

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, completable-future

I just read [***the documentation***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) about `CompletableFuture::runAsync` and was pretty confused by the explanation. Here is what's written there:

> Returns a new `CompletableFuture` that is asynchronously completed by a
>   task running in the given executor after it runs the given action.

As far as I understand it, `CompletableFuture` looks like `Future` with that it can "register" some sort of callbacks and invoke them implicitly once a given action is finished.

Taking that into account, let's consider the following code:

```
ExecutorService threadsPool;
Runnable r;
//...
CompletableFuture.runAsync(r, threadsPool);
```

In this code we register the `Runnable` to be executed asynchronously in the given `ThreadPool`.

But what does it mean ***`CompletableFuture` that is asynchronously completed by a task***. How can the task make the `CompletableFuture` become completed... ? It doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside `CompletableFuture` there is the following code called by `runAsync`.

```
static CompletableFuture<Void> asyncRunStage(Executor e, Runnable f) {
    if (f == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    CompletableFuture<Void> d = new CompletableFuture<Void>();
    e.execute(new AsyncRun(d, f));
    return d;
}
```

`AsyncRun` is the asynchronously executed task that will, after running the `Runnable f`, complete the `CompletableFuture d` asynchronously. I won't bother with the code here because it's not very informative, and it just performs the completion of `d` by calling its `postComplete()` method (the package-private one).

Comment: to add, `CompletableFuture` should not be used every time you need to run smth asynchronously! It uses ForkJoinPool#commonPool() behind which is not without surprises - you can read more here  https://dzone.com/articles/be-aware-of-forkjoinpoolcommonpool

Comment: @walv all the examples in the question and answer use the version which take an `Executor` argument, meaning the common pool will not be used.

Comment: you are right, for this particular example the executor is passed as a second argument. My comment was to aware people about the usage of default `CompletableFuture.runAsync(r:Runnable)` and that link above describes why it might be a problem. Sorry if wasn't clear on my previous comment.