# Java completable future allOf thread attachement

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

There is the `allOf` java `CompletableFuture` method.

In my code, I run separately 5 different tasks on the main pool of my application. Something like that:

```
t1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> ..., mainPoolExecutor);
t2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> ..., mainPoolExecutor);
...
t5 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> ..., mainPoolExecutor);

CompletableFuture.allOf(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5).join()
```

What I found out is that in **99 quantiles** it takes **100ms** for this code to be finished. At the same time, the time taken by the longest task is **50ms** in **99 quantiles**. In my point of view, it happens because my poll has size of 20 threads, sometimes, for example, task t1 and t3 are being executed on the same thread, there is no guarantee from `allOf` method that tasks will be executed on different threads.

If it is correct, how can it be handled? What is the best approach to achieve **50ms in 99 quantiles** for all tasks to be finished?

I don't like the solution of increasing the size of the pool. I am not sure if there is another solution though.

Comment: You can try configuring the initial core pool size to 5 as you will be having minimum of 5 threads at any given time. I think even though you have max pool size has 20 your core pool size is less than 5.

Comment: allOf doesn't run anything. [runAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173509/understanding-completablefuturerunasync) is causing your code to be executed. If you want to make sure all of your tasks are run on a separate thread, then you need to provide them with an executor service that will manage that. What is your "mainPoolExecutor"

Comment: There could be multiple reasons for this outcome including the number of CPUs in your machine. What if you have four cores and hence one thread would always be queued for the other to finish?